# abstract classes C++

Tags: c++, sdl, virtual, abstract

So it is my understanding that to make a class abstract in c++ you have to create one, just one, pure virtual method in that class. In my code i create an abstract GameObject class, which is inherited by my Player class, but the problem is i get errors in my Player.cpp saying error LNK2001: unresolved extrenal symbol "public:virtual void__thiscall GameObject::Load(void)" (?Load@GameObject@@UAEXXZ)    for every method except the initialise, and this gets fixed when i set them all = 0, im just wondering why

```
// Abstract class to provide derived classes with common attributes

#include <SDL.h>
#include "AnimationManager.h"
#include "Debug.h"
#include "InputHandler.h"

class GameObject
{
public:
    virtual void Initialise() = 0;
    virtual void Load();
    virtual void HandleEvents();
    virtual void Update();
    virtual void Draw();
    Vector2D* position;
    int currantFrame;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    float speed;
    bool alive;
};



#include "GameObject.h"

class Player : public GameObject
{
public:
    virtual void Initialise();
    virtual void Load();
    virtual void HandleEvents();
    virtual void Update();
    virtual void Draw();
    Player(SDL_Renderer* r);
    ~Player();
};



#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(SDL_Renderer* r)
{
    renderer = r;
}

Player::~Player()
{
}

void Player::Initialise()
{
    position = new Vector2D(10, 10);
    currantFrame = 0;
}

void Player::Load()
{
    TheAnimationManager::Instance()->load("Assets/circle.png", "player", renderer);
}

void Player::HandleEvents()
{
    SDL_Event event;

    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:

                switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_a:
                        DEBUG_MSG("A Pressed");
                        position->m_x -= 10;
                    break;

                    case SDLK_d:
                        DEBUG_MSG("D Pressed");
                        position->m_x += 10;
                    break;
                }

            break;
        }
    }
}

void Player::Update()
{
    Vector2D* p = TheInputHandler::Instance()->GetMousePosition();
    DEBUG_MSG(p->GetY());
    DEBUG_MSG(p->GetX());

    currantFrame = int(((SDL_GetTicks() / 100) % 4));
}

void Player::Draw()
{
    TheAnimationManager::Instance()->Animate("player", (int)position->GetX(), (int)position->GetY(), 90, 82, 0, currantFrame, renderer, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: 1) Please post the exact error, and the corresponding line.  2) Please make sure that *each* abstract method in your abstract class has a corresponding implementation in your "Player" class (it looks like you're already doing this).  3) Here's a good link: [Abstract base class example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr142.htm)

Comment: edited my question and code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every virtual method which might be called through a base class pointer that isn't pure virtual needs to have an implementation.

You seem to have a backwards idea of how abstract/virtual works.  You don't choose to make a class abstract, why would you?  You choose to make a member function pure virtual, because there is no sensible implementation for it.  Then, as a consequence of having a pure virtual function, the class becomes abstract.

The class becoming abstract does not mean that every one of its functions suddenly becomes pure virtual.

Your error is a linker error.  The linker was looking for the implementation of the `GameObject::Load` function, which you didn't provide.  If you mark the function as pure virtual, the linker won't look for an implementation.

Comment: Not quite. A non-`virtual` method only needs to be defined if it can be called somehow.

Comment: for example, if i take away the = 0 part of the initialise method in the GameObject class, i get this error error LNK2001: unresolved extrenal symbol "public:virtual void__thiscall GameObject::Initialise(void)" (?Initialise@GameObject@@UAEXXZ)

Comment: The reason i choose to make it abstract is because GameObject must never be instantiated, so i make it abstract to make sure it never gets instantiated

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Good point.  Better?  Henrique, I edited it, and even that was wrong.

Comment: The "which is called through a base class pointer" part is wrong.  It's sufficient that it *might* be, in some other compilation unit, which is *really* hard to disprove.  So pretty much, all virtual methods must either have an implementation or be declared pure (non-exclusive OR, that).

Comment: Standard says: "A virtual member function is odr-used if it is not pure."  So it has to be defined even if it provably cannot be called.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: what Ben Voigt said: if a function is `virtual` and not pure, it has to be defined. If it is pure, it can be defined (sorry, couldn't resist messing with that...). Whether it is actually ever called is immaterial.

Comment: @Jake: That's the implementation for `Player`.  `GameObject` needs one, unless you mark it pure virtual.

Comment: ah ok i get ya, the fact i dont have a GameObject.cpp file is my problem, as none of GameObjects methods are being implemented, just inherited and then implemented, but i dont want to have one of those cpp files so i get away with not having one by putting them all as pure virtual

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers require that for each signature the virtual keyword would specified only once, in the base class. Try this:

```
class GameObject
{
public:
    virtual void Initialise() = 0;
    virtual void Load() = 0;
    virtual void HandleEvents() = 0;
    virtual void Update() = 0;
    virtual void Draw() = 0;
...
};

class Player : public GameObject
{
public:
    void Initialise();
    void Load();
    void HandleEvents();
    void Update();
    void Draw();
...
};
```

Comment: Those would not be C++ compilers.

Comment: @BenVoigt: It used to be like that in early VC++, circa 2000. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895294/c-virtual-keyword-for-functions-in-derived-classes-is-it-necessary) and other sources virtual keyword in derived classes should be optional but harmless in modern standards-compliant compilers.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need the public GameObject::Initialise method be pure virtual, at least give it an empty body, like this

```
class GameObject
{
public:
    void Initialise() {}
    ...
};
```

Comment: i give it a body in player though

Answer (score 0):

Another conjecture: do you have, by any chance, any instantiations of GameObject in your code? Do you have something like this:

```
GameObject go;
```

or something like this:

```
void foo( GameObject go );
```

or something like this:

```
GameObject bar();
```

or something like this:

```
vector<GameObject> all_my_objects;
```

Comment: None, i dont want to do that which is exactly why i made it abstract

Comment: Instantiation could have happened accidentally, such as passing GameObject by value instead of by reference, etc.