# Why are override and final identifiers with special meaning instead of reserved keywords?

Tags: c++, c++11, keyword

Both the [override specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) and [final specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) were added in C++11. They differ from other specifiers added to C++11 such as [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) and [decltype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype), in that they are not [keywords](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) and so are available for use as identifiers:

```
int main()
{
  int override = 0 ;    // Ok
  int final = 0 ;       // Ok
  //int constexpr = 0 ; // Error
}
```

They are referred to as *identifiers with special meaning*, which is covered in the draft C++11 standard section `2.11` *[lex.name]* (*emphasis mine*):

> The **identifiers in Table 3 have a special meaning** when appearing
>   in a certain context. When referred to in the grammar, these
>   identifiers are used explicitly rather than using the identifier
>   grammar production. any ambiguity as to whether a given identifier has
>   a special meaning is resolved to interpret the token as a regular
>   identifier.

and *Table 3 -- Identifiers with special meaning* lists both *override* and *final*.

Why did these two specifiers end up being *identifiers with special meaning* instead of *keywords*?

Comment: I thought you [previously established](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311551/is-it-undefined-behavior-to-redefine-an-identifier-with-special-meaning) that it was undefined behavior to redefine identifiers with special meaning?

Comment: @CoryKramer That's for `#define`s. Though @Shafik might want to clarify that question a bit.

Comment: @CoryKramer that is different, you can not `#define` or `#undef`

Comment: @T.C. yeah I think you may be correct, let me think about how to clarify that one better.

Comment: @T.C. okay, I think I clarified the previous question, let me know if you disagree.

Comment: I think the correct question to be asking is the opposite: why so many words are keywords in the first place.

Comment: There is a related question (but not a duplicate) here: [Why “override” is at the end in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28163187/428857)

Comment: @TonyK thank you for pointing me to that question. I don't know how I missed that blog post you have in your answer with all the searches I did, it took me a while to come up with `N3163`

Answer (score 35):

Adding new keywords is difficult because it takes away identifiers from the user. It ends up being a trade-off between choosing identifiers that potentially break old code currently using the identifier or choosing names that are highly unlikely to break old code but are *ugly* or not meaningful to the way they are being used.

In this specific case *override* and *final* end up being used in the grammar in places where no user identifiers can appear. So in those places the identifiers can have a special meaning and outside of those contexts they can be treated as a regular identifier leaving the identifiers available for users. `C++/CLI` has used this technique since `2005` and they are called *context-sensitive keywords* which is covered in the [C++/CLI standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-372.pdf) section `9.1.1` Identifiers.

We can see in the write-up that addresses the trade-offs of the different methods of adding support for virtual control attributes in [N3163: Override Control Using Contextual Keywords](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3163.pdf). It discussed three options:

- Using `[[attributes]]`, which was deemed undesirable for reasons including they are just keywords in disguise (*modified example from paper below*):

  > ```
  > class A : public B {
  >   virtual void f [[override]] () { ... }
  >   virtual void h [[final]] () { ... }
  > };
  > ```
- Use reserved keywords, which potentially breaks existing code unless *ugly names* are chosen (*modified example from paper below*):

  > ```
  > class A : public B {
  >   virtual void f override_func () { ... }
  >   virtual void h final_func () { ... }
  > };
  > ```
- Use context-sensitive keywords, which does not break existing code allows for *nice names* (*modified example from paper below*):

  > ```
  > class A : public B {
  >   virtual void f() override { ... }
  >   virtual void h() final { ... }
  > };
  > ```

The following paragraph from the paper sums up the argument for using *context sensitive keywords* over the other two choices (*emphasis mine*):

> The observation was made in Rapperswil that this approach can make
>   error recovery and syntax highlighting more difficult. For example,
>   syntax highlighting is a bit harder because instead of globally
>   highlighting the keyword you need to do parsing to know whether the
>   identifier is in the location where it has special meaning and should
>   be highlighted. But this is not exceptionally difficult, particularly
>   not in comparison to other far more difficult things we already have
>   to do in C++ compared to other languages .
>
> These are **minor inconveniences for a few compiler writers for a week,
>   but are seamless for users. This is the right tradeoff**. Otherwise,
>   having ugly globally reserved names (Option 2) or inappropriate and
>   visibly bolted
>   - on **attributes (Option 1) make things easier for a few compiler writers for a week, but are things millions of users will have to live
>   with forever**.

The changes were applied to the standard via [N3206: Override control: Eliminating Attributes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3206.htm) and [N3272: Follow-up on override control](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3272.htm).