# Is it a code smell to declare a function to be virtual in a derived class?

Tags: c++

In this code, I have defined three structs, `base`, `derived` and `MoreDerived` each inheriting from the previous member in the list.

However, I have defined the function `f()` to be virtual in the `derived`
struct, *NOT* in the base struct.

```
#include <iostream>
struct base {
    void f() {
       std::cout << "base\n";
   }
};
struct derived : base {
    virtual void f()  { 
        std::cout << "derived\n";
    }
};

struct morederived : derived {
     void f()  { 
        std::cout << "more derived\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    derived d;
    morederived md;

    base* dp = &d; 
    base* mdp = &md; 
    dp->f(); 
    mdp->f(); 

}
```

The code above prints `base \n base` as expected. And if I declare `dp` and `mdp` to be pointers of type `derived*`, the code prints `derived \n more derived` as expected again, since `f` is defined to be virtual in the derived.

Of course, this code is small and so the results are predictable. But in large code bases, is doing the above ever a good idea?

Note: I have not seen this in any codes yet, in my limited c++ experience, nor do I have any plans to use such a pattern (or anti-pattern :-D). I am asking this purely out of curiosity.

EDIT: I don't feel this question is not a duplicate to the one pointed out. I am not asking if the virtual keyword is necessary in a derived class. I am asking the effects/plusses/minuses of placing the virtual keyword on a function `f()` that has an implementation in the base class, but is declared virtual only in the derived class, and then is inherited by other classes. 
Specifically I am asking if this thing is a patter or anti-pattern.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but I'm pretty sure a structure doesn't count as a class... a structure is just meant to hold data like variables and such so therefore it can't hold functions use an actual class to hold functions...

Comment: @CJHutchison you are wrong. In C++ classes and structs are almost the same, differ only in default member visibility (private in classes vs public in structs)

Comment: "However, I have defined the function f() to be virtual in the derived class, NOT in the base class.". From what I know, overriden functions in derived classes will be `virtual` by default, even if you don't declare them as `virtual`

Comment: @CJHutchison In `C++` `struct` is identical to `class` in everything except the default access control.

Comment: oh wow didn't know that thanks for the new knowledge!

Comment: @ CJ Hutchinson Thanks for pointing that out! I have made the edits to say structs instead of classes. However, the question would hold for classes too, since structs are just classes where everything is public by default instead of private as it is for classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ "virtual" keyword for functions in derived classes. Is it necessary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895294/c-virtual-keyword-for-functions-in-derived-classes-is-it-necessary)

Comment: but wouldnt you just have to do morederived.f()? I'm not too great at c++ as well lol so this is something I'm curious about as well

Comment: @Fureeish - C++ is different from Java and functions are not virtual unless you explicitly say so.

Comment: @BoPersson, see the question I flagged as possible duplicate and accepted answer

Comment: Make sure to use the `override` keyword to make it clearer.

Comment: It's not a pattern if it doesn't have a use case. What is its use case?

Comment: @Fureeish The question you linked asks if `derived::f()` needs to be declared `virtual` when `base::f()` is `virtual`; in this case, `derived::f()` overrides `base::f()`.  This question is about whether declaring `derived::f()` virtual when `base::f()` is _not_ `virtual` is good or bad design; in this case, `derived::f()` hides `base::f()`.  They're actually much more different than they look.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this breaks the Is-a contract. Your derived is not playing by the same rules as base.

This is never a good idea. You might want to consider composition for derived. I.e.

```
struct derived {
    base b; // for whatever use you might have for base.
    virtual void f()  { 
        std::cout << "derived\n";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In my book, it qualifies as a code smell.

`derived::f()` actually hides `base::f()` rather than overriding it.

This means that `base_ptr->f()` always calls `base::f()`, even if `base_ptr` points at an instance of a derived class, whereas `derived_ptr->f()` will use virtual function dispatch.

The fact of making `derived::f()` virtual and documenting that it can be overridden, encourages implementers of classes like `morederived` to expect that a call of the form `pointer->f()`, if pointer points at an instance of `morederived`, to believe their version will be called.    In reality, which version will be called depends on the type of pointer (e.g. different version called if it is `base *` or `derived *`).

That can result in quite an unpleasant surprise for anyone who uses the classes, and doesn't closely inspect all classes in the hierarchy.  In large class hierarchies, particularly if provided by someone else, developers will not typically inspect a complete class hierarchy provided by someone else *that* closely.  The will assume it works as advertised, if they care at all about their productivity.

If this sort of thing was present in a commercial class library, the vendor could expect to receive bug reports from customers bitten by such a bug, to lose customers of their library (on the premise that they introduced a bug through bad development technique), or both.