# Polymorphism in C++ (unexpected behaviour)

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I have three following classes:

```
class A
{
private:
    std::string device;
public:
    std::string getDeviceType() { return device; };
    void setDeviceType(std::string device) { device = device; };
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
    virtual void doSomething2() = 0;
};

class B: public A
{
    private:
    public:
        B(){ ; };
        virtual ~B(){ ; };
        void doSomething() { std::cout << "I am usual B" << std::endl; };
        void virtual doSomething2() { std::cout << "I am usual B" << std::endl; };
};

class C : public B
{
private:
public:
    C(){ ; };
    ~C(){ ; };
    void doSomething() { std::cout << "I am C" << std::endl; };
    void doSomething2() { std::cout << "I am C" << std::endl; };
};
```

main:

```
B *myHandler = new C();
myHandler->doSomething();
myHandler->doSomething2();
```

but output is not as expected, my expected output was `I am usual B` and then `I am C`, because `doSomething()` is a non virtual member of class `B`. But the real output was `I am C` and then `I am C`. Do you know why?

Comment: [OT] `{ device = device; }` should be `{ this->device = device; }`, or use different names.

Comment: Overridden methods stay virtual; Since `A::doSomething` is, `B::doSomething` and `C::doSomething` are too, regardless of the repetition of the keyword `virtual` in their declaration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> because of doSomething() is non virtual member of class B

This is where you are mistaken.  In `A` you declare `doSomething()` as `virtual`.  That means that it is [implicitly marked virtual in classes that derive from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895294/c-virtual-keyword-for-functions-in-derived-classes-is-it-necessary).  So `doSomething()` in `B` is `virtual` which means you will call `C`'s `doSomething()`.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that `doSomething` is marked as *virtual* in class `A`. So it remains *virtual* in classes `B` and `C` because they inherit from class `A`.

As this function is *virtual*, it is called according to the real type of the object, which is `C` in your case, and you get the output: `I am C`.

Answer (score 0):

Once marked virtual, it remains virtual in all derived classes.

In C you overrode both doSomething() and doSomething2(). You instantiate C, so the methods of C are called in both cases.

If you omitted the override in C of doSomething(), the output would be as you expected it.

KR,
Melle